# Thread Safe Get and Put method of Map (Performance Testing)

Tags: java, multithreading, performance-testing

I am trying to do some performance testing on my service. So I wrote a multithreaded program for that. It will be hitting my service parallely with few threads and then measuring how much time each thread is taking to come back.

The way I am doing the update and get on the Map will be threadsafe. Right? As I am finding very hard to debug this Mutltithreading Program to see whether my program is working right or not. Can anyone help me out with this Multithreading program

```
private static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long> histogram = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1 * 1000; i++) {
            service.submit(new ThreadTask(i, histogram));
        }

        service.shutdown();

        while (!service.isTerminated()) {

        }

        ThreadTask.report();
    }


class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private int id;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private String result;
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long> mapData;

    public ThreadTask(int id, ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long> histogram) {
        this.id = id;
        this.mapData = histogram;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

            long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            result = restTemplate.getForObject("",  String.class);
            long difference = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time);

            Long count = getMethod(mapData, difference);
            if (count != null) {
                count++;
                putMethod(mapData, difference, count);
            } else {
                putMethod(mapData, difference, Long.valueOf(1L));
            }

    }

    private synchronized void putMethod(ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long> hg2, long difference, Long count) {
        hg2.put(Long.valueOf(difference), count);       
    }

    private synchronized Long getMethod(ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Long> hg2, long difference) {
        return hg2.get(difference);
    }

    public static void report() {
        System.out.println(mapData);
    }
}
```

**Updated Code basis on below suggestion-**

```
    private static RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private static String result = null;
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong> histogram = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 1 * 1000; i++) {
            service.submit(new ThreadTask(i, histogram));
        }

        service.shutdown();

        while (!service.isTerminated()) {

        }

        ThreadTask.report();
    }


class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    private int id;
    private static RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private String result;
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong> hg;

    public ThreadTask(int id, ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong> histogram) {
        this.id = id;
        this.hg = histogram;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

            long start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

            result = restTemplate.getForObject("",  String.class);
            long difference = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start_time);

        final AtomicLong before = hg.putIfAbsent(difference, new AtomicLong(1L));
        if (before != null) {
            before.incrementAndGet();
        }

    }

    public static void report() {
        System.out.println(mapData);
    }
}
```

Can anyone take a look and let me know whether this time I got it right or not?

Comment: Just a suggestion, why not use the guava cache? There is a method of eviction after a write which might exactly be what you need here

Comment: Also, I wouldn't tie your whole class around one implementation type.  For example, instead of taking ConcurrentHashMap, take ConcurrentMap.  Interfaces create better code!

Answer (score 2):

No, your code is definitely **not** thread-safe because the entire update operation is not atomic. You read a value, increment it, and write back. By that time another thread may have incremented the same histogram entry and now you are saving a stale value, effectively "swallowing" a hit.

My suggestion: use `synchronized (histogram) { ... }` around the whole update operation. You don't, however, need the individual synchronized methods.

If you want a lock-free solution, use `ConcurrentHashMap<Long, AtomicLong>` and use this code to update it:

```
final Long before = histogram.putIfAbsent(difference, new AtomicLong(1L));
if (before != null) before.incrementAndGet();
```

Comment: Better yet, make the count an `AtomicLong` and increment it with an atomic operation.

Comment: @ataylor That was my first idea, but how do you initialize it? The code gets very messy and is not worth it.

Comment: Good point.  The guava [MapMaker](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) is a nice way to create thread safe maps with default values correctly.

Comment: @ataylor Actually, I thought it through and the code isn't too complicated. Now that I see it, I'd use that instead of locks. It does waste an instance of `AtomicLong` each time, and if you want to avoid that, then it gets **really** messy.

Comment: Thanks a lot Marko. I have made your suggestion in my code. Updated the question as well with my new code. Can you take a look and suggest me if I did it right or not. I want to learn this stuff as where is the problem if there is any more problem in the code.

Comment: @ataylor. Thanks for your suggestion as well. I have updated my question with latest code I am using.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use synchronized with a ConcurrentHashMap

You should warm up you code by running it many times.  I would ignore the first 10,000 times and run the test for at least 2 to 10 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Peter for the suggestion. So you saying I don't need to synchronized get and put methods of my concurrent hash map? And apart from that my code is fine in getting the historgram of performance? Or any loop hole is there?

Comment: Updating a histogram concurrently can have serious overhead unless your tasks are fairly long.  A more efficient approach is to create a histogram for each thread and combine these when finished. I would use TLongLongHashMap to reduce the overhead of creating objects.

Comment: +1 Your comment is better than your answer :) I'd include that advice into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Guava's [AtomicLongMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicLongMap.html).